# Joint pdf of two uniform random variables on a unit line segment

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, simplex, density-function

Let $X$ be a standard uniform random variable, define $Y=1-X$. Then supposedly $X$ and $Y$ are [uniform over a 1-simplex](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf), so their joint distribution should be Dirichlet of order $K=2$, and $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ . Hence, their joint pdf is $$f(x,y)=1\quad\text{if }x,y\in[0,1]\land x+y=1.$$ My question is, how do I derive the joint pdf from definition? A naive attempt is to notice the joint cdf $$F(x,y)=P(X\leq x,1-X\leq y)=P(1-y\leq X\leq x).$$ But then taking cross derivatives of $F$ seems yield $0$ everywhere...

Comment: Not everywhere, just almost everywhere.  The derivative is not zero along the line $x+y=1$.

Comment: @Paul: can you show how it is done?

Comment: How do you define a *density* on $[0,1]^2$? What makes you think that this example has one?

Comment: @Henry: I thought there is a pdf defined because the setup looks a lot like a flat Dirichlet distribution of order $2$, and numerical experiment does seem to confirm this. Are you saying that they are in fact different things?